# Add content to second column on "Contact Us" page

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, column, contact-form

I've been editing the standard magento contact us page.  Mine is using the 2-column-left.phtml template being called through the contacts.xml.  On my contact page the standard form is being populated in column 1, but the second column isn't being used.  How would I go about adding some basic html content to that second column?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you understand basic theming you can add blocks referencing the left core/text_list block.

So in your custom layout XML file you would add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <contacts_index_index>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="core/template" name="contact.left.template" template="contacts/left.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

Then under app/code/frontend/{PACKAGE_NAME}/{THEME_NAME}/contacts/left.phtml you would add the following:

```
<?php
/** @var $this Mage_Core_Block_Template */
?>
<div class="block block-contact-left">
    <div class="block-title">
        <h3>My Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <p class="block-subtitle">My Subtitle</p>
        <p>Some text here....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should now see something similar to the following image:

[image]